# How can I print a void method inside a button using Swing?

Tags: java, swing

i am pretty new i am sorry if i use terms incorrect. I am trying to learn Swing and import it to my current project. In my main file, a method prints a list from mysql database. I want this : when button pressed, print this output to textfield or dialog window, show on the gui, not only cmd output. I hope I could explain my request correctly. I use Netbeans as IDE.

method in Baglanti.java :

```
public void dogList() {
    String sorg = "Select * From dogs";
     NewJFrame frame1 = new NewJFrame();
     
    
    try {
        statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sorg);
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String species = rs.getString("species");
            int age = rs.getInt("age");
            String owner = rs.getString("owner");
            String date = rs.getString("date");

            System.out.println(" id : " + id + " name: " + name+ " species: " + species+ " age: " + age+ " owner: " + owner+ " date: " + date);
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Baglanti.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

}
```

and my list button in NewJFrame.java

```
private void listbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    Baglanti baglanti = new Baglanti();       
    // i don't know what next
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, let's fix your doglist() method. I have Given it a PrintStream parameter so that it can be used with System.out but also with any other PrintStream. I have also taken out the "NewJFrame" creation. This shouldn't go there.

```
public void dogList(PrintStream stream) {
    String sorg = "Select * From dogs";
     //Take this out
     //NewJFrame frame1 = new NewJFrame();
     
    
    try {
        statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sorg);
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String species = rs.getString("species");
            int age = rs.getInt("age");
            String owner = rs.getString("owner");
            String date = rs.getString("date");

            stream.println(" id : " + id + " name: " + name+ " species: " + species+ " age: " + age+ " owner: " + owner+ " date: " + date);
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Baglanti.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

}
```

Now, all you need is a PrintStream for a JTextField or a Dialog. And the easiest way to get this is to use a ByteArrayOutputStream and then convert that to a String and set it in the JComponent

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream myPS = new PrintStream(bstream);
dogList(myPS);
String msg = new String(bstream.getBytes());
```

Now you can use JTextField.setText(msg), or do something similar within your JFrame/Dialog.

Comment: Thanks it worked ! But "bstream.getBytes" gave an error and  "bstream.toByteArray()" worked correctly for me. Did I missed anything ?

Comment: @bjorke07 No sorry btream.getBytes was wrong and .toByteArray() is the proper correction

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not need to create another instance of `NewJFrame` in `dogList` method of `Baglanti` class.

Also, it may be redundant to create an instance of `Baglanti` class in `NewJFrame` each time when you press on the button.  It would suffice to have a single instance of this class responsible for retrieval of the data from the DB.

Next, you need to refactor the code of `dogList` method so that it begins to return a list of relevant data classes (e.g. `Dog`) to the caller.  Then you'll be able to use this list in the frame and show its data as needed: in a text area, table, list, etc.

That being said, some code snippets:

```java
// data transfer class Dog
public class Dog {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String species;
    private int age;
    private String owner;
    private String date;

    // constructor with all args, getters/setters
}
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class Baglanti {
// ...
    public List<Dog> dogList() {
        String sorg = "Select * From dogs";

        List<Dog> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try (statement = con.createStatement()) { // use try-with-resources to make sure the statement is closed
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sorg);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String species = rs.getString("species");
                int age = rs.getInt("age");
                String owner = rs.getString("owner");
                String date = rs.getString("date");

                System.out.println(" id : " + id + " name: " + name+ " species: " + species+ " age: " + age+ " owner: " + owner+ " date: " + date);

                // assuming all-args constructor is implemented in Dog
                Dog dog = new Dog(id, name, species, age, owner, date);

                result.add(dog);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Baglanti.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return result;
    }
// ... other methods
}
```

Remaining part in `NewJFrame`:

```java
public class NewJFrame extends JFrame {

    Baglanti baglanti = new Baglanti();

//... other UI components

    private void listbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        List<Dog> dogs = baglanti.dogList();

        for (Dog dog : dogs) {
            // set information about the dog in other UI components
            textArea.append(String.format("Dog id=%d named: %s, age %d years, owner: %s",
                dog.getId(), dog.getName(), dog.getAge(), dog.getOwner()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to make my code better with your valuable suggestions.